# Sinon: mocking NodeJs' fs.readFile() not working with sinon.stub()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sails.js, sinon

I'm trying to unit test one of my functions inside a module, which uses other dependencies such as `fs` and the aws-sdk.

The thing is that I cannot mock out the `fs` library..

```
var readFileAsync = Promise.promisify(require('fs').readFile);

function uploadAttachment(fileMetadata) {
    return readFileAsync(fileMetadata.fd)
    .then(function(file) {
      var options = {
       ...
      };
      return _uploadToS3(options);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      return result;
    });
  }
}
```

I've been trying to use Sinon library to stub out the `fs` library `readFile` and my own promisified function.

```
stub = sinon
.stub(fs, 'readFile')
.returns("some data");

promiseStub = sinon
.stub(FileService, 'readFileAsync')
.returns("some data");
```

But when I'm running my tests it doesn't seem to run my stubbed out functions and does not set `calledOne` to be `true`, instead it's running the `fs` function and cannot find a path and throws an error.

```
  [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/file/3f191fa8-4330-436a-9f85-4054f8fa6a67.pdf']
```

Comment: At what point do you create the stubs? Also, `fs.readFile()` doesn't _return_ anything, it calls a callback function (look up `yields()` in the Sinon docs); and the promisified function should return a proper promise (`.returns(Promise.resolve('some data'))`)

Comment: I define them in the top describe function, and create them in the beforeEach funciton. Will check yields out. Thanks man!

Comment: Your code shows that `readFileAsync` might be a local function to your module, in which case you can't (easily) stub it, so that's something to be aware of (esp since it will also wrap the _original_ `fs.readFile`, and will never call a stubbed version of it).

Comment: No luck with yields.. :/ Yeah I know, that kinda sux but I thought that exporting that local function would help but it didn't either.

Comment: Exporting it could work, but only if you call the exported reference inside of your module (so something like `return exports.readFileAsync(fileMetadata.fd)...`); otherwise, you'd also end up calling the original function and not the stubbed reference. You should take a look at [`rewire`](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire), which might be helpful.

Comment: How did you fix this?